# Slim Framework routes returns not found except "get" named ones

Tags: php, slim-3

I use: slim-skeleton (Mr. Rob Allen's scaffold provided on github)

Under /projects grouped routes, only **"get"** method routes work without any problem but with rest of all return `page not found error`. Also these routes have **auth middleware + cors middleware (Cors Middleware taken from Slim Framework's v3 Documentation).**

Here is my ../src/routes.php file:

```
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

// Routes

// Administration
$app->group('/admin', function() use ($app) {

    // Dashboard
    $app->get('/dashboard', 'App\Controllers\Admin\Dashboard:index');

    // Projects and images management
    $app->group('/projects', function() use ($app){


        // Projects Actions
        $app->get('/list', 'App\Controllers\Admin\ProjectManagement:index');
        $app->post('/add', 'App\Controllers\Admin\ProjectManagement:add');    # NOT WORKING
        $app->get('/id/{id}', 'App\Controllers\Admin\ProjectManagement:find');   
        $app->put('/edit/{id}',  'App\Controllers\Admin\ProjectManagement:edit');   # NOT WORKING
        $app->delete('/remove/{id}', 'App\Controllers\Admin\ProjectManagement:remove'); # NOT WORKING

        // Project Images Actions
        $app->get('/{pid}/images', 'App\Controllers\Admin\ProjectImageManagement:attachments');
        $app->post('/{pid}/images/attach', 'App\Controllers\Admin\ProjectImageManagement:attach');


        // Project's Image management
        $app->get('/{pid}/images/id/{id}', 'App\Controllers\Admin\ProjectImageManagement:find');
        $app->put('/{pid}/images/edit/{id}', 'App\Controllers\Admin\ProjectImageManagement:edit');
        $app->delete('/{pid}/images/remove/{id}', 'App\Controllers\Admin\ProjectImageManagement:removeImage');


        /**
         * Project's Image Sort Order
         *
         * Additional Info:
         *
         * GET    /{pid}/images     Retrieves current sort order beforehand
         *
         */

        $app->put('/{pid}/images/order/{id}/resort', 'App\Controllers\Admin\ProjectImageManagement:sortOrder');

    });


    // Page management
    $app->group('/pages', function() use ($app) {

        // About Page
        $app->get('/about/content', 'App\Controllers\Admin\PageManagement:aboutPage');
        $app->put('/about/content/update', 'App\Controllers\Admin\PageManagement:updateAbout');

        // Contact Page
        $app->get('/contact/content', 'App\Controllers\Admin\PageManagement:contactPage');
        $app->put('/contact/content/update', 'App\Controllers\Admin\PageManagement:updateContact');

    });

    // Settings
    $app->group('/settings', function() use ($app) {

        // Account
        $app->get('/account/details', 'App\Controllers\Admin\Settings:accountDetails');
        $app->post('/account/details/apply', 'App\Controllers\Admin\Settings::applyAccountSettingChanges');
    });



})->add($auth);



// Auth
$app->get('/auth/point', 'App\Controllers\AuthController:checkPoint');
$app->post('/auth/login','App\Controllers\AuthController:login');
$app->get('/auth/logout', 'App\Controllers\AuthController:logout');


// Guest
$app->get('/about', 'App\Controllers\Guest\PageContents:about');
$app->get('/contact', 'App\Controllers\Guest\PageContents:contact');
$app->get('/works', 'App\Controllers\Guest\ProjectExplorer:projects');
```

And here is my .htaccess under /public directory:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
  # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment v 
 ariable.
  # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or 
    installed the
  # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
  # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
  # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
  # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
  # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

  # If the above doesn't work you might need to set the `RewriteBase` directive manually, it should be the
  # absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
  # RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I also added **Allow from all**, but it results in same way. But if i have doing something wrong why all other routes created outside of "/projects" work well. For instance,  **Auth related routes work well.**

I know that, I have to see "Method Not Allowed" warning instead of seeing not found. Where am i doing something wrong? Any help would be very appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
  $app->map(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH'], '/{routes:.+}', function($req, $res) {
    $handler = $this->notFoundHandler; // handle using the default Slim page not found handler
    return $handler($req, $res);
});
```

I forgot this one. This mapping hides/exchanges method not allowed page => not found handler. It seems to me as an application based error. Sorry for my carelessness...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to add a `root` for the group you added

```
$app->group('/admin', function(){};
```

Under this you should add

```
$this->get('', function(){/*-----activities----*/});
```

And try to use **$this** while using the groups

Explanation:
when you are using $app you are referring to slim object.
when you are using $this inside your $app->group(){} then you are referring to grouped object which will be responsible for grouping the statements.

So, basically when you use $app inside the group then you make it useless because your slim-app is looking for it on above layer of the code(ie. outside the group). and you are not using group object($this in this case) to declare routes so eventually they are getting declared but not addressed properly.

Comment: Please add some explanation so other can understand !

Comment: added the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$app->map(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH'], '/{routes:.+}', function($req, $res) {
    $handler = $this->notFoundHandler; // handle using the default Slim page not found handler
    return $handler($req, $res);
});
```

I forgot this one. This mapping hides/exchanges method not allowed page => not found handler. It seems to me as an application based error. Sorry for my carelessness...

But in my opinion notFoundHandler is not the right choice for this. A custom error message has to be raised for this situation like 405 Method Not Allowed - (notFoundHandler returns 404)

Comment: you should not do this like this, 
write your custom MethodNotAlowed handler: 
http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/handlers/not-allowed.html

Comment: also, edit and add this post to your initial topic description; it is important where you calling this part of code

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :). I exchanged with a custom handler after i posted this. I am to going to add this into question area.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the case, but if you need to change $app->get or $app->post to $this->get or $this->post if you group the routes.

Comment: Hi Toni, i resolved my issue it's caused by not found handler. Thanks for your helps.